# How to put an acronym for the first time without showing the long name using the acro package?

Tags: acronyms, acro

I'm dealing with the acronyms in my thesis using the `acro` package, however, I don't want to see the full long name of a few acronyms. How can I call for the first time an acronym, without showing its full long name?

A MWE: I want to see only UV instead Ultraviolet (UV)

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{acro}

\DeclareAcronym{N}{
short=N,
long=Number
}
\DeclareAcronym{UV}{
short=UV,
long=Ultraviolet
}
\begin{document}
The first acronym I want to see the long name for the first time \ac{N}.
However, the second one, I don't want to see the long form
when I call it \ac{UV}

\printacronyms
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can mark an acronym as used:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{acro}

\DeclareAcronym{N}{
short=N,
long=Number
}
\DeclareAcronym{UV}{
short=UV,
long=Ultraviolet
}
\begin{document}
The first acronym I want to see the long name for the first time \ac{N}.
However, the second one, I don't want to see the long form
when I call it \acuse{UV}\ac{UV}

\printacronyms
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Unless `mark-as-used=first` is supplied as a package option, `\acs{UV}` should do the same as `\acuse{UV}\ac{UV}`.